# VBA- Adicionar linha inteira em uma ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox

Estou tentando adicionar uma linha inteira em um listbox, baseado no resultado de uma pesquisa `.Find`, a ideia é ao achar o valor que bate com o termo pesquisado ele adiciona cada linha que contenha esse valor na listbox.

Tentei alguma maneiras que não deram certo.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim a As Range
    Dim pesquisa As Range
    Dim valor As String
    Dim resultado As Range
    Dim resultadoAnterior As Range
    Dim intervalo As Range
    Dim linha As Range


    Set intervalo = Range("B1:B100")

    With frmPesquisa

        valor = Me.TextBox1.Value + "*"

        Set resultado = intervalo.Find(valor, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

        Do

            Set resultadoAnterior = resultado
            Set resultado = intervalo.Find(valor, After:=resultadoAnterior, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)


            linha = resultadoAnterior.EntireRow


            ListBox1.AddItem (linha)

        Loop Until resultado.Row < resultadoAnterior.Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero ter ajudado, retorna o número da linha e não todo o conteúdo da linha, já que a função *EntireRow* não oferece essa possibilidade. Sugiro um retorno em finção do número da linha em que der *macth*, e essa função retorna toda a linha ou o valores contidos nela.
Segue o código...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Range
    Dim pesquisa As Range
    Dim valor As String
    'Dim resultado As Range
    'Dim resultadoAnterior As Range
    Dim intervalo As Range
    Dim linha As Range
    Dim primeiroMtach As Integer

    Range("A1").Select
    Set intervalo = Range("B1:B100")

    ListBox1.Clear 'limpa listbox

    With frmPesquisa

        valor = Me.TextBox1.Value + "*"

        'Set resultado = intervalo.Find(valor, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        Cells.Find(What:=valor, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
            :=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            primeiroMtach = ActiveCell.Row
            ListBox1.AddItem (ActiveCell.Row)

        For Each celula In intervalo

            Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
            If ActiveCell.Row = primeiroMtach Then
                Exit For
            End If
            ListBox1.AddItem (ActiveCell.Row)

        Next

    End With
End Sub
```